# MutationObserver records wrong DOM Element (editable div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Consider the following:

I have a `contenteditable` div:

```
<div id="contentEditableDiv" contenteditable="true">
    <p id="content0e">Lorem ipsum...</p>
    <p id="content1e">Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

I add a MutationObserver to observe DOM changes in this div in JavaScript:

```
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        manipulateAddedContent(mutation);
    });
});

mutationObserver.observe(jQuery("#contentEditableDiv")[0], 
    { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });
```

After solving this issue I want to `manipulateAddedContent`. Yet the function is declared like this:

```
function manipulateAddedContent(mutation){
    jqMutation = jQuery(mutation);
    if(jqMutation.prop("addedNodes").length > 0){
        for (i = 0; i < jqMutation.prop("addedNodes").length; i++) {
            console.log(mutation.addedNodes[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In the `contenteditable` div it is possible to add a new `p` DOM Element by pressing enter inside an existing `p` element, so the HTML looks like:

```
Inspector:
    <div id="contentEditableDiv" contenteditable="true" style="...">
        <p id="content0e">Lorem ipsum...</p>
        <p id="content1e">Lorem ipsum...</p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
```

But the MutationObserver records the already existing `p` element with `id="content1e"`.

Well, with the anticipation that the MutationObserver won´t do it right, I am also happy if you could give me an alternative solution.

Below is a Stack Snippet. If you click with the cursor inside one of the existing `p` elements and press enter a new `p` element gets created. The MutationObserver records the already existing `p` element, but not the newly created one.

Stack Snippet:

```js
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
  manipulateAddedContent(mutation);
 });
});

mutationObserver.observe(jQuery("#contentEditableDiv")[0], 
  { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });

function manipulateAddedContent(mutation){
 jqMutation = jQuery(mutation);
 if(jqMutation.prop("addedNodes").length > 0){
  for (i = 0; i < jqMutation.prop("addedNodes").length; i++) {
      console.log(mutation.addedNodes[i]);
  }
 }
}
```

```css
 #contentEditableDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
 }

 #contentEditableDiv p{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contentEditableDiv" contenteditable="true" >
  <p id="content0">Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <p id="content1">Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

So why does the MutationObserver records the wrong Element?

How can I fix it? => How get the newly added `p` element (without id)?

Comment: The manipulateAddedContent it is only logging the 1st node observed (mutation.addedNodes[0]). Could it be that it's just not logging all the affected nodes?

Comment: No I add a change in the question. The `for` loop only gives me the `p` with `id="content1e"`. The new `p` element gets recorded after I add a second one.

Comment: Could you pull the code together into a single [mcve]? Maybe use a [Stack Snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/215552) or jsfiddle.net or something? That would make it a lot easier to follow along.

Comment: Thanks for that tip. I compressed the question and deleted the unrelevant content loading part. I really don´t know why I decided it would be important at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is quite simple. I just let me get the next DOM element of the returned one:

```js
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
 mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
  manipulateAddedContent(mutation);
 });
});

mutationObserver.observe(jQuery("#contentEditableDiv")[0], 
  { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true });

function manipulateAddedContent(mutation){
 jqMutation = jQuery(mutation);
 if(jqMutation.prop("addedNodes").length > 0){
  for (i = 0; i < jqMutation.prop("addedNodes").length; i++) {
      if(typeof jQuery(mutation.addedNodes[i]).next()[0] !== "undefined"){
       console.log(jQuery(mutation.addedNodes[i]).next()[0]);
      }
  }
 }
}
```

```css
 #contentEditableDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
 }

 #contentEditableDiv p{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contentEditableDiv" contenteditable="true" >
  <p id="content0">Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <p id="content1">Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

But I will not accept my answer cause I still do not know WHY the `mutationObserver` returns the wrong element.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `MutationObserver`, it's not returning the wrong element. When you press enter inside any element within a `contenteditable` container it gets duplicated, which is why the element reported by `MutationObserver` has the same id. If you try to locate the element through DevTools, it will show you the most recently added one - because it has the same id.

```css
#uniqueOrIsIt {
 border: 1px solid gold;
}
.paragraph {
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p id="uniqueOrIsIt">text</p>
  <p class="paragraph">text</p>
  <p style="border: 1px solid green;color:green">text</p>
</div>
```

All three of the `p` elements will get duplicated with the exact same attributes.

The solution depends on what you're trying to accomplish - do you want each inserted `p` element to have a new unique id? In that case you can, for each mutation, check if any of the `addedNodes` are `p` elements and if they are, assign them a unique id. Keep a simple `let counter = 1` and set the ids as `addedNode.setAttribute('id', ('content' + counter++))`